# Como puedo visualizar un PDF del storage con Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, laravel-6, vuex

tengo un archivo en el *storage*, (este archivo lo puede subir el usuario sin problemas) y tras subirlo y guardarlo, me regresa con una etiqueta `<a href="la ruta del storage">Download</a>` con la ruta donde esta el archivo. Pero al momento de que hago click sobre la etiqueta me muestra la ruta correcta en la *URL*, sin embargo la página se ve en blanco, mi duda es como hacer para visualizarlo en el navegador, es un archivo PDF que se guarda en la carpeta *storage* (publica), despues se vincula con la etiqueta `<a>`

Anexo la pantalla tras cargar el archivo en el storage, PD: esta prueba la realice tanto en Local como en un servidor de pruebas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno el código esta más a nivel de componente con el html, estoy ocupando vue, donde con la petición axios me carga el objeto `feedback.feedbackfiles` e itera con `file` en el ciclo;

```
<div class="list-group">
     <a class="list-group-item 
        list-group-item-action" 
        v-for="file in feedback.feedbackfiles" 
        :href="'/storage/companies/' + cid + 
        '/postulations/files/' + 
        postulation.id + '/' + 
        file.path">
     {{ file.name }}</a>
</div>
```

Funciono, realmente no efectue cambios en el codigo o en las rutas, solo cerré mi sesión e inicie de nuevo, es extraño, realmente la sesión o el cache pudo afectar? les anexo las imagenes en seguida:

**Visualización tras iniciar sesión de nuevo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Sin modificaciones en componente ni rutas:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ruta local fisica**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código. Y ten en cuenta que la ruta a nivel sistema operativo no es lo mismo que la de la url

Comment: Y revisa la doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls

Comment: No se ve lo que pones en la imagen, está muy pequeño. Podrías poner como texto la url y el path? Por ejemplo: el archivo está en `mi-proyecto/storage/app/public/...` y la url es `mi-dominio/storage/...`.

Comment: También aclara si creaste el link simbólico

Comment: Hay algo que no comprendo, ya funciono, realmente no moví cambios en mi código, solo cerré sesión e ingrese de nuevo y los enlaces se abrieron de manera normal, cache a caso?

Comment: Ja, puede ser ¯_(ツ)_/¯